# How to calculate the value of a resistor with just the total voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis, series

It's a series circuit with a total voltage of 20 V.

- R1:  10 kΩ
- R2:  ? but 6V
- R3:  5 kΩ

Must find R2.

How can I get it without the current?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6BC7T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You know that the current is the same in all of the resistors, even if you don't know the current yet. You also know Ohm's Law and the voltage across one of the resistors. Have you tried setting up a [system of equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_equations) representing your system and solving it? Doing so will both solve this question and allow you to derive a shortcut approach for solving this problem in the future. If you've already tried this and got stuck, please [edit]  your post to reflect it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to understand your question, but I think you have this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp3gRP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If that is correct then:

- You can combine the two known resistors into one to simplify the circuit.
- You can use your known voltage drop to calculate the voltage drop across your now combined known resistance
- You can use that calculated voltage drop to calculate the current through the known resistance
- You can use that calculated current with your known 6V voltage drop to calculate the resistance of your unknown resistor.

For this specific case you have:

- Combined resistance: 15kΩ
- Voltage across 15kΩ = 20V - 6V = 14V
- Current through 15kΩ = 14V / 15kΩ = 933µA
- Unknown resistance = 6V / 933µA = 6.43kΩ

Or you can do similar using the voltage divider rules.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Its about what it looks like in the book. The 20V is dc. R1 is at the top and R2 at the bottom instead but i dont think it makes a difference.

Comment: The order of series resistors makes no difference to the current flowing through them.

Comment: You mean R1 + R2 = 15 and 20V / 15 will return 1.33 Ampere. The answer is suppose to be 6.4kohm. I dont know how they get that.

Comment: @FrankDuc You missed out step number 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i still have to figure out each step.

Comment: @FrankDuc I have added a section to the end of my answer with all the calculations.

Comment: I wrote your calculation in my notes to study for the test next week. I am surprise it is possible to get the Ampere by dividing remaining voltage by R1 + R3. Meaning 933uA is also the Ampere of R1 and R3. Make sense 933uA * R1 and R3, the sum return 14V.